# Clear the filter cell value in the XamGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, xamgrid

I am working on **XamGrid** using **MVVM** architectural style while removing the filter using the below code, the filter get removed but the ***filter cell*** still contains the ***filter value*** which should be empty.

```
foreach (var columnBase in dataGrid.FilteringSettings.RowFiltersCollection)
 {
    var col = (RowsFilter)columnBase;
    col.Column.FilterColumnSettings.FilterCellValue = string.Empty;
 }

  dataGrid.FilteringSettings.RowFiltersCollection.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

After long analysis find that you will find such code at many places but the most important thing is your **FilterScope** which should be set to **ColumnLayout** i.e

> dataGrid.FilteringSettings.FilteringScope =
>   FilteringScope.ColumnLayout;

```
RowFiltersCollection rfc = dataGrid.FilteringSettings.RowFiltersCollection;
if (rfc != null)
{
  foreach (RowsFilter RF in rfc)
   {
      if (RF.Conditions.Count != 0)           
            RF.Conditions.Clear();
   }
}

dataGrid.FilteringSettings.RowFiltersCollection.Clear();
```